# wxPython's isChecked() responses are inconsistent- why?

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib, popupmenu

I have a graph with a popup menu that appears when the user right-clicks. Sub-option A is checked by default. I would like the user to be able to toggle this check mark for different behaviors. Thus, I would like to know if A is already checked or not, and I would like this to be handled in its own function. Let's call the function creating the menu showPopupMenu() and the function that needs to know the check status of A commandA().

Right now if I check A by default and print out the IsChecked() status of A, in showPopupMenu() the value is True and in commandA() the value is false. If A is unchecked by default the answers are inverted- showPopupMenu() shows the check status as false and commandA() shows it as true. This makes it seem like the IsChecked() status in commandA() is simply the reverse of the IsChecked() status in showPopupMenu(). Why is this?

```
import wxversion
wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WX')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import wx


class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,
                     'Example Frame',size=(550,350))

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.NamedColor("WHITE"))

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)

        self.axes.plot(t,s)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN,
                   self.showPopupMenu)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def showPopupMenu(self, event):
        if not hasattr(self, "popupTwo"):
            self.popupOne = wx.NewId()
            self.popupTwo = wx.NewId()
            self.popupThree = wx.NewId()
            self.popupA = wx.NewId()
            self.popupB = wx.NewId()

    self.popupOne = wx.Menu()
    my_a = self.popupOne.Append(self.popupA, "A", kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
    self.popupOne.Append(self.popupB, "B")
    self.popupOne.Check(self.popupA, True)
    #self.popupOne.Check(self.popupA, False)
    print "in showPopupMenu(): ",self.popupOne.IsChecked(self.popupA)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.commandA, my_a) 

        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.AppendMenu(-1, 'One', self.popupOne)
        menu.Append(self.popupTwo, "Two")
        menu.Append(self.popupThree, "Three")

        self.PopupMenu(menu)
        menu.Destroy()

    def commandA(self, event):
    print "in commandA(): ", self.popupOne.IsChecked(self.popupA)

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Output of this script:

in showPopupMenu(): True

in commandA(): False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on A, the check mark switches from True to False, which is why you see it output False there. However, you create and destroy your window every time which is why you never see it change the check state.

Here is an example of how to set up the menu without creating and destroying it every time:

```
import wx
import gui

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent)

        # Layout my frame
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.showPopupMenu)
        sizer.Add( self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 0 )
        self.SetSizer( sizer )
        self.Layout()

        # Add the menu
        self.popupA = wx.NewId()
        self.popupOne = wx.Menu()

        my_a = self.popupOne.Append(self.popupA, "A", kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        self.popupOne.Check(self.popupA, True)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.commandA, my_a)

        self.menu = wx.Menu()
        self.menu.AppendMenu(-1, 'One', self.popupOne)

    def showPopupMenu(self, event):
        print "in showPopupMenu(): ",self.popupOne.IsChecked(self.popupA)
        self.PopupMenu(self.menu)

    def commandA(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        print "in commandA(): ", self.popupOne.IsChecked(self.popupA)

class app(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.m_frame = MainFrame(None)
        self.m_frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.m_frame)
        return True

app = app(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Aha! What a simple answer... no wonder my code wasn't working! Thank you so much for the explanation & for the example!